# Sup pages can't be found

Tags: pages, htaccess

I am currently learning about creating and modifying themes for WP and I am stuck on this one thing. I see that there are a lot of people with similar problem but I didn't find a solution to mine.

The problem is that pages work fine and the content is displayed but the content of sub-pages (child-pages) are not found. I have created page with sub-page with content but wordpress just can't find it. Firstly I thought that its my theme problem but after switching to default themes (twenty fifteen,sixteen,seventeen) the result is the same so is it .htaccess problem?
If so I have the default .htaccess and I never changed anything in it.

I also tried switching back and forth between permalink settings - same result.

Thank you.

Edit:
To be clear, there is no error 404 just my 
    `if ( have_posts() ) :`
goes straight to else. Original themes if clause goes to else too.

Edit2:
Thank you @BlueSuiter.
Changing the slug of the parent fixed the problem. Switching it back made the problem again. Does anyone know why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: Is there any taxonomy in your website, with same slug as of parent page?

Comment: Nope the hierarchy is Categories -> Computer monitors

Comment: Change the slug of parent page, reset permalinks and then try to run it again.

Comment: Just so I can mark it solved. > Thank you @BlueSuiter. Changing the slug of the parent fixed the problem. Switching it back made the problem again. Does anyone know why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: This was happened because of slug conflict. There must be same slug assigned to some of the taxonomy. There is no internal check for this in WordPress.